# How to use inline syntax highlighting from minted inside tabular column

Tags: tables, columns, minted

I want to display single lines (not whole blocks) of code in a `tabular` column. The result should work with `longtable` as well.

I defined a shorthand for inline highlighting using [minted](https://github.com/gpoore/minted). It allows to specify its content using a custom delimiter just after the inline command. I tried to put this into a column definition, but I end up with an error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{minted}
\newmintinline[mycode]{c}{showspaces}
\begin{document}
\mycode{void foo()} % delimiter "{"
\mycode|int bar()|  % delimtier "|"
\mycode'int baz()'  % delimiter "'"
% does not work with any of the delimiters above 
\begin{tabular}{>{\mycode'}c<{'}} 
    void main()
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The error is:

> || File ended while scanning use of \minted@inline@ii.

Is there any way to achieve this? What is my mistake?

#### EDIT (Guilherme):

Other possibility should be to make this sort of code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\usepackage{minted}
\newmintinline[mycode]{c}{showspaces}

\begin{document}
% does not work with any of the delimiters above 
\begin{tabular}{>{\mycode'}l<{'}p{5cm}} 
\toprule
\midrule
void foo() & This function is used to do great things in C\\
int bar() & This is probably making its argument and integer \\
int baz() & This other is the same as the former\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Output this:

[image]

Comment: Maybe there's a way, but using `>{...}` and `<...` is unfortunately not apt to the job.

Comment: You should have a look at David Carlisle's answer to this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332042/using-mhchem-with-array which also involve the formatting of columns using the `array` package.

Comment: @DRi, take a look at egreg's comment above. Apparently that sort of approach won't manage this, at least not with my knowledge of TeX...

Comment: I am not a `minted` person, so maybe this question is elementary...what do you want the output to look like?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes What the OP (and I) wants is to have a column of code formatted by `\mintinline` but without having to issue the command every time. Something like the `>{\bfseries}` to make it bold but make it `minted` instead. Was that clear or do you prefer I edit the question to provide visual example? `:D`

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos A visual example always helps, and it is certainly appropriate for a bounty giver to edit someone else's question.  I am just pondering whether the same visual effect can be generated with a different verbatim approach.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, there you go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `verbatimbox` approach that uses `<` and `>` as the escape characters.  The syntax is not as clean as even the original syntax to overcome, because the verbatimboxes need to be created before the `tabular` invocation.  In that sense, it offers no improvement whatsoever.  However, `verbatimbox` does not require a `shell-escape` to execute, so that is something.  My main goal was to see if it could be done with the `verbatimbox` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,xcolor}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\def\mycode{}
\let\svspace\ %
\catcode`>=\active %
\catcode`<=\active %
\def\openesc{\color{red!75!black}\def\ {\spconvert}}
\def\spconvert{\color{black}\textvisiblespace\color{blue!80!black}}
\def\closeesc{\color{black}\let\ \svspace}
\def\vbdelim{\catcode`<=\active\catcode`>=\active%
\def<{\openesc}\def>{\closeesc}}
\catcode`>=12 %
\catcode`<=12 %
\begin{document}
\begin{myverbbox}[\vbdelim]{\voidfoo}xxx <void foo()>\end{myverbbox}
\begin{myverbbox}[\vbdelim] {\intbar}x<int bar()> etc.\end{myverbbox}
\begin{myverbbox}[\vbdelim] {\intbaz}<int baz ()>\end{myverbbox}
\begin{tabular}{lp{5cm}} 
\toprule
\voidfoo & This function is used to do great things in C\\
\intbar & This is probably making its argument and integer \\
\intbaz & This other is the same as the former\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I obviously changed the verbatim content slightly, to demonstrate the parsing abilities of the approach.  If I remove the extraneous stuff, I get what is actually desired:

[image]

Comment: This is nice, but as you said I'd have to create the boxes beforehand so in the end it's pretty much as having to write `\mycode` to every table line... `:/` I know I didn't specified in the question, and that's why I won't complain, but the use of `minted` is important as its already been used on the whole document.

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos I understand completely.  Since I wrote `verbatimbox`, I wanted to see if it was possible to produce the result.  I fully appreciate that the syntax is not as good as even the original, but at least `verbatimbox` doesn't require shell-escape to compile.