# Using mhchem with array

Tags: arrays, mhchem

I would like to use the array package to format a column filled with chemical formula in order to avoid writing `\ce{X}` on each line. I don't know if it is even possible. I started from the trick used to hide a column, but didn't get very far.
My code is :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
        \newcolumntype{F}{>{\hbox\bgroup\ce{}}l<{\egroup}@{}}
        \newcolumntype{H}{>{\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup}c<{\egroup}@{}}
        \newcolumntype{N}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3cm}}
        \newcolumntype{M}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\begin{array}{N F M}
\toprule
Name & Formula & MW\\ 
&& (Da) \\
\midrule
glycol & C2H6O2 & 62.07\\ 
glycerol & C3H8O3 & 92.09\\ 
 & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{array}  

\end{document}
```

What I am looking for, is a command like
`\newcolumntype{F}{????}`
which can format the content of the column as a chemical formula

Comment: @David Carlisle The \raggedleft doesn't really matter, I will replace c by l, but what I don't know is how to apply the \ce{} command which argument should be the content of the column. But maybe it is simply not possible ?

Comment: Have a look at the `collcell` package

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your MWE generates an error about `array` not in math mode, but youwant `tabular` here.

As the `\ce` is not in the last column, you can pick up the cell contents with a delimited argument.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}
        \newcolumntype{F}{>{\zzz}l<{\relax}@{}}
        \newcolumntype{H}{>{\setbox0=\hbox\bgroup}c<{\egroup}@{}}
        \newcolumntype{N}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3cm}}
        \newcolumntype{M}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}}
\def\zzz#1\relax{\ce{#1}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{N F M}
\toprule
Name & Formula & MW\\ 
&& (Da) \\
\midrule
glycol & C2H6O2 & 62.07\\ 
glycerol & C3H8O3 & 92.09\\ 
 & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You are right, I meant the tabular environment (I got confused with the array package). This is exactly the kind of code I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `collcell` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% tabular material:
\usepackage{array,booktabs,collcell}
\newcolumntype{F}{>{\collectcell\ce}l<{\endcollectcell}}

% sciences:
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}% version 4 is the current one
\usepackage{siunitx}% provides column type `S' for aligned numbers

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lFS[table-format=2.2]}
  \toprule
    Name & Formula & {MW} \\
    & & {(Da)} \\
  \midrule
    glycol   & C2H6O2 & 62.07 \\ 
    glycerol & C3H8O3 & 92.09 \\ 
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The example above also uses the `siunitx` package and its column type `S` for aligned numbers.

Comment: I didn't know the collcell package, but it seems interesting since it avoid the creation of a new macro. I knew the use of siunitx with array. Thanks